# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007000d

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I casually downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Microsoft Store. But when I ran it, this appears:

**Installing, this may take a few minutes...**

**WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007000d**

**Error: 0x8007000d The data is invalid.**

**Press any key to continue...**

Does anybody here have any solution to this issue? I have tried downloading again and enabling the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature. Thanks for your help.

Comment: seems like it is a bug https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6592, just like here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-resolve-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with/0b218e4d-581e-4a60-9392-626cb19d20d2 try to update and reboot after enabling the wsl option